# add paint component to a JPanel

Tags: jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm trying to create an object from this class and add it to a JPanel in my main class. So when I add it straight to the frame, and not the panel, it works fine. But I need to add multiple objects so I need three JPanels. PLEASE HELP ME!

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] Args) {
    GuessProp prop = new GuessProp();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel pan = new JPanel();

    pan.add(prop);
    frame.add(pan);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

vvvv This is the code from the class I'm adding vvvv

```
public class GuessProp extends JComponent {
static ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

static int next;
static int last;
static Integer count = new Integer(0);
static int acurate = 50;
final static double threshold = 0.75;

public GuessProp()
{
    Timer time;
    time = new Timer(100, new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                nextRand();
                guess();
                count++;
                repaint();
            }
        });
        time.start();
}

/*ASSUME THE IMPLEMENTATION FOR METHODS:
     *nextRand() AND guess() 
     *ARE HERE AND WORK FINE...
     */

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Rectangle plot = new Rectangle(50,acurate, 10, 10);
    Line2D.Double base = new Line2D.Double(25,55,75,55);
    g2.setColor(Color.red);
    g2.fill(plot);
    g2.setColor(Color.black);
    g2.draw(base);
    g2.drawString(count.toString(), 100, 50);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The object being added to the JPanel, in this case the paintComponent, need to extend JPanel which already inherits from JComponent. Also setting the frame layout for more than one panel is good...

Answer (score 0):

> *"But I need to add multiple objects so I need three JPanels."*

What you need to understand about `JFrame` is that is has a default `BorderLayout`. When you add only one component to it, it will appear fine, as the frame will inherently add the component to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position. If you try and add more than one, you need to specify which position each component should go. The most commonly used positions are

```
BorderLayout.WEST
BorderLayout.EAST   
BorderLayout.NORTH
BorderLayout.CENTER
BorderLayout.SOUTH
```

Where the positioning will look like this

[image]

So you would add component like this

```
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

As good practice, a `CENTER` should generally be used at least once. Also note, position can contain only one component.

So what it you have more than five components you want to add?

- You could set a different layout.
- You could use a `JPanel` for the content pane and set the layout for that panel.
- You could use nested `JPanel` with nested `LayoutManagers`.

---

See the [Laying Out Components Within a Container tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) where you can learn all the different layouts.

---

> *"I'm trying to create an object from this class and add it to a JPanel in my main class."*

If this means what I think it means, where you want to add components to the `JPanel` being painted, I would rethink that, ass you will add the components over the painting of the `JPanel`. Instead the the painting `JPanel` as its own component that only caries the painting, then add more components to the frame, as shown above.